# JavaScript onselect for p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

We have a **p** tag in the page, and we will detect selecting this with JavaScript `onselect` or something like this, Perhaps this select can be triggered by mouse or keyboard, and also we can not use of `onmouseup` or `onclick`!

```
<p onselect="alert('selected')" >My p text is here ...</p>
```

`onselect` works with dropdown and textbox, and do not work with p tag.

Comment: As you say, `select` is not an event raised by the `p` tag. You could instead use `onclick', but the method you're using here is far from best practices. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Perhaps select by keyboard ! then my method not worked !

Answer (score 0):

You could use **onclick**, if it suits your needs then:

```
$("body").delegate("p", "click", function(){
  alert('selected');
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @Majid Shahmohammadi .This will invoke keypress with jquery $(document).keydown(function (e) {  alert(e.keyCode) }); You will get  which key pressed

Comment: i know this worked by keypress and mouseup or click, but i will work by onselect because must use of two method for detected this.

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer and Webkit, you can use:

```
somedom.addEventListener('selectstart',callback)
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this event fires when you start selecting, rather than when you've finished selecting.

Comment: var obj = document.getElementById('test2');
obj.addEventlistener('selectstart',function(){
 alert(234);
})

Comment: obj.addEventlistener is not a function !!

Comment: @MajidShahmohammadi: `addEventListener`.

Answer (score -2):

By default a **p** tatg is not selectable, you can set it selectable with this short code:

```
$('p')
  .attr("tabIndex", 0)
  .css({"-moz-user-select": "none","-webkit-user-select": "none","-khtml-user-select": "none"})
  .attr("unselectable", "on");
```

Comment: ‮I think your answer is a bit backwards.

Comment: What you describe that the code does and what it actually does are two different things.

Comment: ...noitseuq eht dootsrednusim evah tsum I ,yrroS